# Invalid id on record type update

Tags: apex, record-type, exception, dml

A trigger to update an opportunity record type, sends to `@future` method. I get this error:

> 15:24:49.22 (45149525)|FATAL_ERROR|System.StringException: Invalid id: rt.id

Debug shows it does call a proper record type with right name, etc.

Here is the class:

```
public class OppRecTypeFuture {

    @future
    public static void FutureOppTypeMethod (set<id>Opportunities){



    RecordType  RT = [select id, name, DeveloperName from recordtype where Name = 'BIZLineA' limit 1];
        system.debug('RT---------------------------------------'+rt);
    List <Opportunity> Ops = [select id from Opportunity where id IN: Opportunities];    
        for (opportunity O:Ops ) {
            o.RecordTypeId='rt.id';
        }  
        database.update(ops,false);
    }

}
```

Assigned improperly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the approach below as well, it will save you 1 DML statement:

```
public class OppRecTypeFuture {

    @future
    public static void FutureOppTypeMethod (Set<id> opportunities){

        Id RT_ID = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('BIZLineA').getRecordTypeId();
        List<Opportunity> ops = [select id from Opportunity where id IN: opportunities];    
        for (opportunity o : ops ) {
            o.RecordTypeId = RT_ID;
        }  
        database.update(ops,false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes around it.

**Fails**

```
o.RecordTypeId = 'rt.Id';
```

**Succeeds**

```
o.RecordTypeId = rt.id;
```